# Adding annotations to a Jersey multipart-form-data function breaks it

Tags: java, tomcat, annotations, jersey, multipartform-data

I have Tomcat Jersey service that's supposed to accept files alongside other parameters. The following code illustrates the use case:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/fileupload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void post(@FormDataParam("file")File file, @FormDataParam("fileType")String fileType) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
//Your local disk path where you want to store the file
        String uploadedFileLocation = "C://AlienTemp/" + file.getName();
        System.out.println(uploadedFileLocation);
        System.out.println(fileType);
        // save it
        File objFile=new File(uploadedFileLocation);
        if(objFile.exists())
        {
            objFile.delete();
        }

        saveToFile(new FileInputStream(file), uploadedFileLocation);
    }

    private void saveToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                            String uploadedFileLocation) {
        try {
            OutputStream out = null;
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The upload in itself works but only if I remove the fileType parameter and *all* annotations. If any annotation is present it doesn't work. Tomcat throws a useless 400 error: "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.". If I don't specify any annotation then the servlet doesn't start, throwing a resource error.

In other words, the upload request succeeds only if one parameter is present (file) with no annotations whatsoever.

Other details:

- Tomcat: 8.0.21 embedded
- Jersey: 2.22.1
- Client: Postman app in Chrome
- Java: 1.8

Why are annotations not working?

EDIT 1:

This is what the server outputs:

```
Apr 10, 2016 5:04:51 AM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 2 * Server has received a request on thread http-nio-8070-exec-2
2 > POST http://localhost:8070/web/feaf/fileupload
2 > accept: */*
2 > accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
2 > accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
2 > cache-control: no-cache
2 > connection: keep-alive
2 > content-length: 3903
2 > content-type: multipart/form-data
2 > host: localhost:8070
2 > origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
2 > postman-token: 4eb8418b-9976-ca61-6d0e-f98c7d96d3b8
2 > user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36

Apr 10, 2016 5:04:51 AM org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 2 * Server responded with a response on thread http-nio-8070-exec-2
2 < 400
```

Here's a screenshot of Postman: [image]

EDIT 2:

Here's the web.xml. I had to change the service name and cut out some irrelevant servlets.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyWebservice</display-name>  
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>status.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>    

    <!-- RESTful services -->    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>feaf Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>web.feaf</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>feaf Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/web/feaf/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

EDIT 3:

Thanks to @Sanj, it turns out that Jersey rejects requests with the multipart-form-data in the header, at least from Postman. Sending an empty header fixes the problem.

Comment: Can you post an image of the Postman client (with all the request settings). And are there any errors/exceptions in the server log?

Comment: I can't see any exceptions in the server log. The only thing I get is a debug message that says that status 400 was returned. See edit.

Comment: You didn't add the `fileType` part in Postman. See if adding that fixes it

Comment: If you want to get the content-type of the `file` part, then instead you should use `@FormDataParam("file")` [`FormDataContentDisposition`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.0/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/media/multipart/FormDataContentDisposition.html) instead of another `fileType` part.

Comment: can you share web.xml?

Comment: @peeskillet It doesn't matter whether fileType is specified or not. The result is the same. The reason I need fileType is not to receive the extension but the kind of processing that needs to be performed on the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks good. There could be a problem with either dependencies(pom.xml) or web.xml.

Here is the working file upload example using jersey 2.22.1 @ https://github.com/shaimakh/so36524919

Here are the dependencies and web.xml from my example:

pom.xml(dependencies)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Restful File Upload</display-name>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.foo.rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

Postman Output

[image: Postman Output]

Comment: Thanks for the Git repo, Sanj! I downloaded the code, imported it in IntelliJ Idea as a Maven project and then built a WAR. I deployed the WAR to my Tomcat but I it still doesn't work with Postman. Now it throws a [405 error](http://imgur.com/bb6hwh2). Surprisingly, the upload returns status 204 if I use the form you made. There seems to be something wrong with the configuration in Postman.

Comment: With this endpoint I get the classical 400 Bad Request, just like with my code. Can you verify that it works on your side with Postman?

Comment: So your Postman works just as well as the form UI? What are the exact parameters/headers that you used?

Comment: Yes - Postman works for me. Form params file and/or fileType. I am not adding any headers - basically using default Postman settings.

Comment: Yes!! It was the header all along. I can't believe Jersey is so stupid to reject the request just because it has the right header (multipart form data). Thank you so much!